# How to make an action in Redux with multiple fetches when one of them gets response with delay?

Tags: javascript, promise, redux, fetch, redux-thunk

I'm thinking on how to implement the following action in Redux:

1. The first fetch gets search data with its id (api endpoint: `/searches/:id`)
2. Its response has `status` which can be equal to `in_progress` or `finished`
3. I need to run the second fetch only when first request's response is equal to `finished`
4. The second fetch takes the same id and gets next data (api endpoint: `searches/:id/results`)

I'm confused on how to make the action, because I don't know how to repeat first fetch till it gets `status: finished` in response. And only then start next fetch to get results.

Here is how I'm trying to do it (I'm using redux-thunk):

```
export const fetchResults = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  return fetch(`/searches/${id}`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => dispatch(fetchUntilFinished(data.id)))
  .then(res => {
    if (res === true) { // allowed to make next fetch
      fetch(`/searches/${id}/results`, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(results => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_RESULTS',
          results: results
        })
      })
    }
  })

function fetchUntilFinished(id) {
  fetch(`/searches/${id}`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
  }
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
     if (data.status !=== 'finished') {
       fetchUntilFinished(id);
    } else {
       return true; // to trigger that next fetch can be done
    }
  })
}
```

And it doesn't work this way. I'm not even sure if I'm trying to do it proper way. I need help or ideas on how to implement such action.

Comment: Maybe it's a little too much, but did you tried to wrap fetch with a Promise and resolve the promise when you get desired status? Fetch implements a promise-like interface so it suits well there.

Comment: @sunpietro No, don't really know how to wrap it with Promise. Could you please make a pseudo code example?

Comment: `fetchUntilFinished` isn't returning anything

Comment: try a `return` before `fetch(/searches/${id}, {` ... and another one before `fetchUntilFinished(id);` in the `if (data.status !=== 'finished') {` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dair you can try something like this:

```
let interval;
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    interval = setInterval(() => {
        fetch('your-url').then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 'finished') {
                clearInterval(interval);
                resolve(response);
            }
        })
    }, 1000);
});

promise.then(doYourStuffAfterResponse);
```

It's not perfect but it gives you an idea.

Comment: this code will keep on fetching even after status === finished

Comment: Yes, it continues fetching. How can I stop it?

Comment: Of course, it will. You have to store the interval in a variable and when it reaches required status then the interval should be cleared with `clearInterval(variableWithIntervalRef)`

Comment: Could you please edit your answer with clearInterval?

Comment: Thank you so much, trying it. Will get back shortly with results!

Comment: Such an elegant way, works flawlessly! Thank you a lot!

Comment: using interval may cause a big memory leak. not advised to use this

Comment: @JaromandaX because over the network you can be sure that you will get the response in 1 second. if there is a slow network you can end up in multiple calls to the server because of the interval. which you will want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

what I think is you should not mix redux actions with the API call. 
both of them should be separate. you can make an API call. get the data and dispatch the action after that. this will give you better control over the data.
you may want to format it a little bit before you can store it in the store.

I use axios instead of fetch. but they both do the same task. so here is what i do in these kinda cases. 
i have a seperate function that makes api calls only. in a seperate file. for simplicity i will do everything at one place.
enter code here

```
function makeRequest(serviceConfig) {

    let serviceObject;
    try {


        serviceObject = {
          url: serviceConfig.baseUrl + serviceConfig.url,
          method: serviceConfig.method,
          params: serviceConfig.params || {},
          data: serviceConfig.data || {},
          headers: serviceConfig.headers || {},
          withCredentials: (serviceConfig.withCredentials === true),
        };
      } 
      return axios(serviceObject).then((response) => {
          return  response ;
      }, (error) => {
           return error;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  },
```

Now call the request make function with all the particular config

```
requestmaker({
   baseUrlType :'yourdomain.com',
   url:'searches/2',
   method:'GET',
   params:{},
   data:{},
   headers:{}
}).then((success)=>{
     if(success.status==='finished'){
     /*call request maker again with new params.*/ 

        requestmaker({
           baseUrlType :'yourdomain.com',
           url:'searches/2/results',
           method:'GET',
           params:{},
           data:{},
           headers:{}
       }).then((nextSuccess)=>{
         // here nextSuccess will contain the final result set.
          dispatch({
              type: 'FETCH_RESULTS',
               results: nextSuccess
               })
         })
   }
 },(error)=>{
 // your error handeler 
 });
```

Comment: Thank you! Will check your solution a bit later. Memory leak is really a big concern.

Comment: using interval in a API method is bad because it will be making server calls until you get the data, so there is a possibility that if you have slow network or server didn't respond well you will end up in multiple requests send one after another.